# What is preventing my search bar from scaling to proper size?

Tags: html, css

My search bar won't scale to the proper size when I adjust the size of my window.

Here ist my code

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="roladeck-main">
            <nav class="nav-bar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <h2>Sample</h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <form>
                            <input for="websearch" type="text" placeholder="Search for cards..." required size="1"/>
                            <button id="websearch" type="submit">
                                <img src="Pictures/search-icon.png" alt="Search" height="10">
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <h2>Sample</h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
<body>
```

here is the style sheet:

```
.nav-bar{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 .nav-bar ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}   

.nav-bar li:hover{
    background: rgb(197, 197, 197);
}
 .nav-bar li{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
.nav-bar input {
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I tried deleting the float left of the style sheet which allows the search bar to scale, but it keeps my list elements from lining up.